# How can I change the current user(in apex) or give "Connection User" access to the Connect API?

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce2salesforce, connect-api

I am trying to write code that will post to an objects chatter feed and mention a list of users so they will get a push notification on salesforce1. This code will be a batch which is run from a trigger when a record is inserted in to my org(via salesforce2salesforce). When a record is created this way the trigger is run under the context of "Connection User". This is a problem because "Connection User" does not have access to the Connect API. How can I change the current user(in apex) or give "Connection User" access to the Connect API?

Here is an example error message and code:

> Error inserting ChatterTest record(s). Cannot insert ChatterTest
>   (ChatterTest Name : R9). Message: ChatterTestPost: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.NoAccessException: Insufficient
>   Privileges: The Connect API is not enabled for this user type. (System
>   Code) Class.ChatterTest.EventWatchChatterSetup: line 57, column 1
>   Trigger.ChatterTestPost: line 3, column 1 . StatusCode =
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY.

```
global with sharing class ChatterTest implements Database.batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{

global ChatterTest(){
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.batchableContext info){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [select Id, SomeText__c
        from  ChatterTest__c
        where NotificationSent__c = false // get all those events where notifications haven't been sent yet
        limit 10000]); // hardcoded for testing
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Database.executebatch(new ChatterTest());
}

global void execute(Database.batchableContext BC, List<ChatterTest__c> scope){
    for (ChatterTest__c anEvent : scope){
        EventWatchChatterSetup (anEvent.id, anEvent.SomeText__c);
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}

private static void EventWatchChatterSetup (Id eventId, String msg) {
    // First have the users follow the Event feed
    // Use EntitySubscription:
    //EntitySubscription entSub = new EntitySubscription (parentId = new Event's Id,
    //                    subscriberid = userId);
    List<EntitySubscription> newSubs = new List<EntitySubscription>();
    newSubs.add(new EntitySubscription(parentId = eventId,
                                       subscriberid = '005j000000BaH7L'));
    Database.insert(newSubs, false);

    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

    messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

    textSegmentInput.text = msg;
    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

    // Mention a user
    mentionSegmentInput.id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // replace XXXXXXXXXXXXX with your user id
    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

    feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
    feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;

    // Use a record ID for the subject ID.
    feedItemInput.subjectId = eventId;

    ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput, null);        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - I don't think you can. I've had similar problems when trying to get a guest site user to write to Chatter.

If you are running a batch, you could have to have some scheduler that starts a batch every few minutes - and have the batch kick off a new one if there are records to process - that way, the batch would run in the right context. Dan Appleman has done some [good presentations](http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/design-patternsasynchronousapex) on how to create that sort of continuos loop.

As a side note - if you are bulk adding FeedItem records, I would suggest using the new [BatchInput](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_batch.htm) feature in the Connect API to avoid DML limits